# How do I force a release in iOS5? Or Is there a better way to do this with UILabel?

Tags: memory, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am writing a fairly simple application which spawns a thread which ultimately calls the following method to put a UILabel at a certain location. I had expected ARC to clean up the labels as the method closed. I was wrong. :)

Is there a way to force these to be cleaned up or is there something obvious that I am missing? Thanks!

```
-(void) drawNumberLabel:(NSString *)labelText xloc:(float)xLocation yLoc:(float)yLocation {

    UILabel *tempLabel;
    tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xLocation, yLocation, 27.0, 59.0)];
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize];
    tempLabel.text = labelText;
    tempLabel.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    tempLabel.textColor = textColor;
    [self addSubview:tempLabel];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "clean up the labels"? Are you expecting that tempLabel would be deallocated at the end of this method? It won't, because when you call `[self addSubview:tempLabel]`, your view retains the label. When the superview is deallocated, the labels you've added will also be deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), you should never make any memory management calls because the compiler will insert these statements for you at compile-time.

The compiler should be injecting **[tempLabel release];** to the end of your method at compile-time.

However, because you have added the label as a subview to a view, the containing view will retain the label, and the label will not be released until you remove the label from that view.

Comment: Thanks for the response and I agree that should be the behavior. I'm going to look elsewhere in the code to see if there is something holding on to those somehow. Thank you for confirming what I was assuming!!

Comment: Thanks!  My pleasure to help you with this problem.

Comment: If you feel that I helped you with this issue, could you vote my answer up?  Thanks, and good luck!